# Rails remote renders a page of json and the JS ajax handler doesn't catch

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I would like a form to post remotely, and then get some JSON back that my JS knows what to do with. Code:

```
<%= form_tag '/admin/order_lookup', remote: true, authenticity_token: true, id: "order-lookup-submit" do -%>
  <%= text_field_tag 'contact_string' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end -%>

$("#order-lookup-submit").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) { 
  alert("in success")
})

def order_lookup
  # some code
  render json: @result
end
```

When I do the `POST`, what happens is I correctly get the JSON, but in a page of just JSON (URL: `http://localhost:3000/admin/order_lookup`).

Obviously I don't want that, I want the ajax event handler to catch the JSON. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render json: @result}
end
```

in like every possible way, and I keep getting ActionController:UnknownFormat. Haven't successfully debugged that according to conventional logic either.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the respond_to with .json?

```
format.json {render json: @result.to_json}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form_tag to the following:

```
form_tag '/admin/order_lookup.json', remote: true, authenticity_token: true, id: "order-lookup-submit"
```

Notice the appended json on the location.

I've created a demo app to illustrate this working.

testing.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#order-lookup-submit").on("ajax:success",function(event){
    alert("success");
  }).on("ajax:error",function(event,x,y){
    alert("error");
  });
});
```

order_lookup.html.haml

```
= form_tag '/admin/order_lookup.json', remote: true, authenticity_token: true, id: "order-lookup-submit" do 
  = hidden_field_tag "testing", "testing"
  = submit_tag "submit"
```

Controller

```
class TestingController < ApplicationController
   def order_lookup
     return render json: {hi: "hi"}
   end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root "testing#index"
   post "admin/order_lookup" => "testing#order_lookup"
end
```

Comment: same thing happens

Comment: James - updated the answer - it should be fine with .json

Comment: James - when you submit the form, is the page itself posting and displaying the JSON?

Comment: yes, like literaly it's a page of the json response

Comment: I'm able to replicate your issue by removing 

//= require jquery_ujs

from the javascript manifest.  Do you have the necessary dependencies in your asset pipeline to make asynchronous form requests?

Comment: yes, like i do this elsewhere, that's why it's so weird, i just copied pasted my otoher working code into here

Comment: James - if you can update your question with a public github repository containing a rails app demonstrating the issue - I'm sure we'll be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: thanks, this is for a small thing so not worth the crazy time investment already, since rails is keen on rendering the `order_lookup` template no matter what, i will give it a template in html to work with. thanks for your patience